# Testing Spring Controller class public method

Tags: spring, database, testing, junit, controller

I need to test a public method in spring Controller class. Unfortunately my understanding of Spring is miniscule. All i know is that there are 2 repository classes that are wired to database and the method i want to test retrieves record from both databases like in the example:

```
@Controller
public class CalculateController {
    static double ZERO = 0.00;
    static double PROFIT_BOUND = 0.01;
    static int DECIMAL_PLACES = 2;
    static double MARGIN_PERCENT = 10;
    static double PERCENT_DIVIDER = 100;
    static boolean renderTable = false;

    @Autowired (required = false)
    private StateRepository stateRepository;


    @Autowired (required = false)
    private ProductRepository productRepository;


    @Autowired (required = false)
    private InternationalTransportCostsRepository internationalTransportCostsRepository;
// some other code unrelated to topic

 public Double[] calculateProfitUSA(State state, Product product, Double finalPrice) {
        Double[] tab;
        if (getTax(state.getId(), product.getCategory()) == ZERO) {
            tab = calculateMarginWithoutTaxUSA(state, product, finalPrice);
        } else {
            tab = calculateMarginWithTaxUSA(state, product, finalPrice);
        }
        return tab;
    }
private Double[] calculateMarginWithTaxUSA(State state, Product product, Double finalPrice) {
        Double[] tab = new Double[3];
        double profit = calcUSA(state, product, finalPrice);
        double estimatedPrice = (product.getCurrentPrice() + state.getTransportCost());
        estimatedPrice = estimatedPrice + (estimatedPrice * (getTax(state.getId(), product.getCategory()) / PERCENT_DIVIDER));
        double margin = estimatedPrice * MARGIN_PERCENT / PERCENT_DIVIDER;
        estimatedPrice = estimatedPrice + (estimatedPrice * MARGIN_PERCENT / PERCENT_DIVIDER);

        double currentProfit = calcUSA(state, product, estimatedPrice);
        while (currentProfit < margin) {
            estimatedPrice += PROFIT_BOUND;
            currentProfit = calcUSA(state, product, estimatedPrice);
        }
        tab[0] = Precision.round(profit, DECIMAL_PLACES);
        tab[1] = Precision.round(estimatedPrice, DECIMAL_PLACES);
        tab[2] = Precision.round(margin, DECIMAL_PLACES);
        return tab;
    }
  public Double getTax(Long id, String categoryName) {
        if (categoryName.equals("Groceries")) {
            return stateRepository.findById(id).get().getGroceriesTax();
        } else if (categoryName.equals("Prepared-food")) {
            return stateRepository.findById(id).get().getPreparedFoodTax();
        } else if (categoryName.equals("Prescription-drug")) {
            return stateRepository.findById(id).get().getPrescriptionDrugTax();
        } else if (categoryName.equals("Non-prescription-drug")) {
            return stateRepository.findById(id).get().getNonPrescriptionDrugTax();
        } else if (categoryName.equals("Clothing")) {
            return stateRepository.findById(id).get().getClothingTax();
        } else if (categoryName.equals("Intangibles")) {
            return stateRepository.findById(id).get().getIntangiblesTax();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I have been trying to search a solution on google for 2 days, I failed. All i managed to come up with is this:

```
@WebMvcTest(CalculateController.class)
public class CalculateAlgorithmsTests {

    @InjectMocks
    private CalculateController calc;
    @Mock
    private StateRepository stateRepository;
    @Mock
    private ProductRepository productRepository;
    private List<State> states;
    private List<Product> products;


    @Test
    public void calculateProfitUSATest(){
        states = CSVReader.readStatesFromCSV("csvFiles/states.csv");
        products = CSVReader.readProductsFromCSV("csvFiles/products.csv");
        productRepository.saveAll(CSVReader.readProductsFromCSV("csvFiles/products.csv"));
        stateRepository.saveAll(CSVReader.readStatesFromCSV("csvFiles/states.csv"));
        State Connecticut = states.get(5);
        Product Apple = products.get(0);
        double [] expected = {25,12,32};
        Assertions.assertEquals(expected,calc.calculateProfitUSA(Connecticut,Apple,30.23));
    }
}
```

And I get this response from console:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present

    at java.base/java.util.Optional.get(Optional.java:141)
    at com.taxcalc.controllers.CalculateController.getTax(CalculateController.java:215)
    at com.taxcalc.controllers.CalculateController.calculateProfitUSA(CalculateController.java:167)
    at com.taxcalc.CalculateAlgorithmsTests.calculateProfitUSATest(CalculateAlgorithmsTests.java:41)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:675)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:117)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:184)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:180)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:127)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1507)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1507)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is no result for your given id when calling `stateRepository.findById(id)`.

You should mock that in your test by using sth like

```
State someState = new State()
Mockito.when(stateRepository.findById(someId)).thenReturn(Optional.of(someState))
```

You need to make sure that `someId` has the same value as the `State` you are calling the public method with.

The calls of `stateRepository.saveAll()` could then be omitted because you would explicitly mock the behaviour rather than using the given data from the CSV.
This is just a suggestion.
Another suggestion is to move this kind of logic into a service. Controllers usually define the HTTP related behaviour rather than haven business logic.

Comment: It worked perfectly! I only had to cast someState argument to java.util.Optional.ofNullable and it worked just fine. Thank you.